# Pagination stays on same page for post category

Tags: php, pagination

I have a custom taxonomy for a group of posts, and I also have a need to show these posts on a custom page template. I want to show one post at a time, with pagination, so that the user can click through them like a slide show.

My template correctly grabs the right category and display one (the first) post, but when I try to click through the pagination, it sends me to the archives for the next post. I want to click "next" and be taken to the next post within the same page template.

I've working with [this solution](http://bloggingsquared.com/qa/solution-wordpress-pagination-stays-on-same-page/), but I can't get it to work.

Here's my code, as it is...

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="full-page">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="full-main-col">
            <a href="#" id="share" rel="prettySociable" title="Drag to Share"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/share.png" alt="" /></a>

            <?php if (have_posts()) :
                            while (have_posts()) :
                            the_post(); ?>

                                <div id="page-head">
                                    <?php the_title('<h1>', '</h1>');
                                    if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs(); ?>
                                </div>

                           <?php endwhile;
                        endif; ?>
            <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar-right.php' ); ?>

            <?php
              query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'fieldtrips', 'fieldtripcategory' => 'elementary-school-aquifer', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
              if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            ?>

              <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
              <?php the_content(); ?>

              <?php previous_post('&laquo; &laquo; %', '', 'yes'); ?> | <?php next_post('% &raquo; &raquo; ', '', 'yes'); ?>

            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you read [Querying Posts Without query_posts](http://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/). Using `query_posts` is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

## query_posts = [_your_doing_it_wrong](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/251)

as soon as you throw in that nasty query_posts you are killing off all the global variables and your paging will not work.

change:

```
 query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'fieldtrips', 'fieldtripcategory' => 'elementary-school-aquifer', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
              if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

to:

```
   $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'fieldtrips',
                                    'fieldtripcategory' => 'elementary-school-aquifer',
                                     'order' => 'ASC',
                                     'posts_per_page' => 1
                          ));
                  if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
```

Also remove the wp_reset_query.

Answer (score 0):

`previous_posts()` and `next_posts()` are deprecated. Try these instead:

[get_next_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post)

[get_next_posts_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link)

[get_previous_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post)

[get_previous_posts_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_posts_link)